# How can I see the AWS API Gateway deployed hyperlink as an output in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am running terraform 0.12.24

I have an api-gateway.tf file where I create the AWS API Gateway resources.

I am planning on deploying an AWS API Gateway like so:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "Example Api Gateway"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  stage_name  = "test"
}

output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.invoke_url
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on main.tf line 126, in output "base_url":
 126:   value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.invoke_url

A managed resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment"
has not been declared in the root module.
```

Why can I not output the API Gateway link as an output when I do a terraform plan?

Comment: Obviously this guide can: https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/aws/lambda-api-gateway

Comment: At a glance that looks fine to me. Can you make sure that your question meets the criteria of a [mcve] please? Right now you can't apply that current config out because it's at least missing methods on the API gateway so no one can reproduce your error directly.

Comment: That could actually be the root cause here, because sometimes this error is thrown when it is actually the resource itself that is invalid.